# Can I force text to break down in exactly word?

Tags: css, break

For example, I got a title:

**"Lorem Ipsum for WordPress"**

It will be display like this in my screen:

```
Lorem Ipsum for
WordPress
```

But I want to display like this:

```
Lorem Ipsum
for WordPress
```

Can I have any solution in CSS? I dont want to use `<br>`

Thank you.

Comment: What are the criteria?  Or any logic?

Comment: i thing u want to this http://tinkerbin.com/wqij7cE8

Comment: Thank you all, I got an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to prevent a line break between two words, as in “for WordPress”, then the simplest way is to use a no−break space (U+00A0) instead of a normal space. If you do not know how to type no−break space in your authoring environment, use the `&nbsp;` entity, as in `for&nbsp;WordPress`.

Alternatively, wrap the words inside `nobr` markup, as in `<nobr>for WordPress</nobr>`, or inside a `span` element to which the CSS declaration `white-space: nowrap` has been assigned.

Comment: 'non-breaking space' not no-break space.

Comment: @Adam, the name is NO-BREAK SPACE in the Unicode Standard as well as in the ISO 8859 family of standards.

Comment: Kiitos Jukka, I used `nobr` tag, either `white-space`, both worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Set width whatever you want.

```
<p>"Lorem Ipsum for WordPress"</p>
p {
width: 95px;
}
```

or you can use two different para

```
  <p>"Lorem Ipsum </p><p>for WordPress"</p>
```

DEMO: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VVe99/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><span style="display:block">Lorem Ipsum</span>for Wordpress</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

May  not possible  by just using CSS  but  you can do using span + a CSS  Display as block  as shown below

```
<p><span>Lorem Ipsum</span><span>for WordPress</span></p>

CSS:

p span 
{
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `white-space:pre-line` [DEMO](http://tinkerbin.com/a5llgncy)